# How can I configure shiny-server to run via NGINX on Ubuntu?

Tags: nginx, shiny, shiny-server, nginx-location

I am trying to configure a NGINX server so that a shiny server and shiny applications can be run via NGINX with proper password protection. My NGINX default file is shown in the example below:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /srv/shiny-server/;
    #index index.html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_bind 127.0.0.1;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
        proxy_redirect http://localhost:8080/ $scheme://$host/;
        auth_basic "Username and Password are required"; 
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

When I go to localhost:80 the shiny welcome page is displayed but the two apps "hello" and "rmd" does not run (See screenshot below).[image]

Doesn anyone have a clue about what I am doing wrong here?

Help would be highly appreciated.

Kasper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how the default file in nginx "sites-available" is supposed to look like. Remember to also configure the R shiny server file.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
            proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080/ $scheme://$host/;
            auth_basic "Username and Password are required"; 
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused on why port 8080 is being used here, shiny-server is accessed via 3838, why is that not used here? I'm trying to skip the user auth and just have nginx direct port 80 to shiny at 3838

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the location of your app in the cofiguration file of nginx too, such as :

```
location /hello {
    proxy_bind 127.0.0.1;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/hello;
}
```